# Magento Payment Gateway Configuration Issue with more than one Model

Tags: payment-gateway, configuration

I've been looking for documentation that explains this in details, but alas i can't find anything that covers config.xml and payment definitions.

I would like to know what is the relation between config.xml and $_code inside a payment module?

This is the config.xml in my module:

```

```
<modules>
   <ACME_Corporation>
     <version>xxx</version>
   </ACME_Corporation>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <acme>
            <class>ACME_Corporation_Block</class>
        </acme>
    </blocks>

    <models>
        <acme>
            <class>ACME_Corporation_Model</class>
        </acme>
    </models>

    <helpers>
        <acme>
            <class>ACME_Corporation_Helper</class>
        </acme>
    </helpers>

    <payment>
        <groups>
            <acme>ACME</acme>
        </groups>
    </payment>
</global>

<default>
    <payment>
        <acme_gold>
            <model>acme/gold</model>
        </acme_gold>
        <acme_silver>
            <model>acme/silver</model>
        </acme_silver>
     </payment>
</default>
```

```

And this are my two models:

`class ACME_Corporation_Model_Gold extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'acme_gold';
}`

`class ACME_Corporation_Model_Silver extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'acme_silver';
}`

However upon checkout neither of them is visible.

If i change `$_code` variable, on one of the Models:

`class ACME_Corporation_Model_Silver extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'acme';
}`

I can see the option in the Checkout form, but this makes naming inconsistent and the second Option is still missing.

I appreciate all the help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incredibly simple, yet no-one mentioned this:

In order to have two separate models working as two payment methods, you need two separate configurations matching the model `$_code` variable. This happens because the Payment Helper pulls the list of payment modules by looking at the saved configuration settings.